# Custom Control WPF binding to parent elements

Tags: wpf, binding, custom-controls

I implemented a custom control and I need to perform some binding.

```
public class SomeControl : Control
    {
        internal static DependencyProperty AProperty;
        internal static DependencyProperty BProperty;
        internal static DependencyProperty CProperty;

        static AnimationControl()
        {

            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AnimationControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AnimationControl)));

            AProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(double), typeof(SomeControl));
            BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(Boolean), typeof(SomeControl));
            CProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("C", typeof(String), typeof(SomeControl));

        }

        public double A
        {
            get { return (double)this.GetValue(AProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
        }

        public Boolean B
        {
            get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(BProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BProperty, value); }
        }

        public String C
        {
            get { return (String)this.GetValue(CProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CProperty, value); }
        }

    }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="speedsBoxChanged" Name="speedsBox" Text="1, 2, 3, 4, 5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" />
        <Slider Name="slider" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="2" Minimum="20" Maximum="750" />
    <local:AnimationControl                               
                                    A="{Binding A}"
                                    B="{Binding B}"
                                    C="{Binding C}" />
<CheckBox Name="versionCheckBox" Click="VersionChanged" IsChecked="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public double A
        {
            get { return lri.Speed; }
            set
            {
                lri.Speed = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("A"));
                }
            }
        }

        public string C
        {
            get { return speedsBox.Text; }
            set
            {
                speedsBox.Text = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("B"));
                }
            }
        }

        public Boolean B
        {
            get { return (Boolean)versionCheckBox.IsChecked; }
            set
            {
                versionCheckBox.IsChecked = (Boolean)value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("C"));
                }
            }
        }
```

But nothing is working, why? I've been trying and trying to figure this out and still nothing. Basically, I want to update animation speed (lri.Speed) with the slider value changed, to update C property from the TextBox and to update B from a checkbox.

Comment: In SomeControl B is Boolean and C is String, in MainWindow.cs B is String and C is Boolean. Maybe you should give your variables more meaningful names.

Comment: In reality it's correct, I changed variable names on purpase, sorry for mistake. It is not the problem though :(

Answer (score 0):

If you define your own control and use the **Binding**, Binding properties should be set in **Style** for your control otherwise they will *not work*:

Sample:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimationControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimationControl}">

            ... set the variables via TemplateBinding....

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 </Style>
```

See the similar question:

[Custom Control Dependency Property Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896619/custom-control-dependency-property-binding)